# Python: Adding an entry?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to write a program that asks a user to enter a product name, the price, and quantity. From there, all the info will be added to a table (dictionary?) Also, an ID number must be assigned to all new items created. I'm confused about the ID number segment.

```
items = {}

product = str(input("Enter the name of a product: "))
price = int(input("Enter a price: "))
quantity = int(input("Enter a quantity: "))

#Assign unique ID number.
```

I'm trying to get the result below as an example:

```
ID#70271, shoes. 7 available, at $77.00
```

Comment: You're going to have to elaborate on the requirements for your ID number. You should also list what you've tried for generating ID numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [uuid4](http://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid4) to create the unique id

```
>>> from uuid import uuid4
>>> uuid4().clock_seq
7972L
>>> uuid4().clock_seq
11807L
>>> uuid4().clock_seq
15487L
```

Comment: I have a feeling that's going to be massively overkill for product numbers... Certainly wouldn't want to be keying those in, in a store or something ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
items = {}
import hashlib
product = "dinosaur"
price = 10.99
quantity = 20
uid = hashlib.md5(product).hexdigest() #is one way but you probably don't
# need a hash if you just want simple number id's: a much easier way is 
otheruid = len(items) # just have the next item be the UID
items[otheruid] = (product, price, quantity)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to be able to retrieve the information? You might consider multiple dictionary keys, or just want to use a tuple or list.

You will almost certainly need to import something to create the ID, especially if it's going to be random. Here is some code that adds that info to an already existing filled or empty list.

```
def storesInfo(product,quantity,price,listInfo): #takes list as a variable
    import random
    ID = random.randrange(0,10000)
    listInfo.append([product,price,quantity,ID])
    return('ID%s, %s. %f available, at %f.'%(ID, product, quantity, price),listInfo)

def main():
    product = str(input("Enter the name of a product: "))
    price = int(input("Enter a price: "))
    quantity = int(input("Enter a quantity: "))
    listA = [[2983, 'socks',32,65.23],[9291,'gloves',98,29.00]]
    print(storesInfo(product,quantity,price,listA))

main()
```

Comment: Yes, I need to retrieve the info. Also, is there a way to do this without importing any modules?

Comment: No, in order to create a random ID, the module must be imported. If nonrandom IDs are alright, then you don't need it.